# Want to have a slideDown() that contains an anchor tag to open automatically when the page is loaded

Tags: jquery, html

Sorry if the question is confusing, here it is broken down:

I have a link like so: http://www.example.com/stuff.stm#stuff

Now when that link is clicked it goes to a page that contains multiple slideDown()'s that haven't been slid down yet, as in the content is still hidden.

How do I go about having the relevant section opened (slideDown() activated, and the page scrolled to the proper anchor) so that the content the anchor is pointing at shows up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(window).on('hashchange', function(e){
    $(window.location.hash).slideDown();
});
```

This worked if your anchor linked to slideDown target element.